# Get Clients and Resources in Keycloak authorization server through SPI

Tags: oauth, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

With the help of SPI (Service provider interface) in keycloak, it is possible to include users from external databases to be part of the users in keycloak. (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_user-storage-spi)

But as I was looking for some documents or articles that explain how it is possible to import pre-defined clients and also Resources within clients (In the authorization tab) from a database with the help of SPI, I ran into no results.

[image]

[image]

I was wondering if there is a possibility to read Clients and Resources information from external databases through service provider interfaces. And through what interfaces it can be done?

Migration from a legacy session-based application to a token-based application with Keycloak and since all user data and other information persisted in the database, I am trying to find a solution to transfer this information.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, and I haven't figured out the answer, but a look at the source code did show that there are several implementation for a ClientProvider. I have tried creating the following class:

```
public class DatastoreClientProvider implements ClientProvider, ClientScopeProvider {
   protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DatastoreClientProvider.class);
   protected KeycloakSession session;
   protected Datastore datastore;

   public DatastoreClientProvider(KeycloakSession session, Datastore datastore) {
       this.session = session;
       this.datastore = datastore;
   }
    @Override
    public Stream<ClientModel> getClientsStream(RealmModel realmModel, Integer integer, Integer integer1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientModel addClient(RealmModel realmModel, String s, String s1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getClientsCount(RealmModel realmModel) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<ClientModel> getAlwaysDisplayInConsoleClientsStream(RealmModel realmModel) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeClient(RealmModel realmModel, String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeClients(RealmModel realmModel) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addClientScopes(RealmModel realmModel, ClientModel clientModel, Set<ClientScopeModel> set, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeClientScope(RealmModel realmModel, ClientModel clientModel, ClientScopeModel clientScopeModel) {

    }

    @Override
    public Map<ClientModel, Set<String>> getAllRedirectUrisOfEnabledClients(RealmModel realmModel) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<ClientScopeModel> getClientScopesStream(RealmModel realmModel) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientScopeModel addClientScope(RealmModel realmModel, String s, String s1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeClientScope(RealmModel realmModel, String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeClientScopes(RealmModel realmModel) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public ClientModel getClientById(RealmModel realmModel, String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientModel getClientByClientId(RealmModel realmModel, String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<ClientModel> searchClientsByClientIdStream(RealmModel realmModel, String s, Integer integer, Integer integer1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<ClientModel> searchClientsByAttributes(RealmModel realmModel, Map<String, String> map, Integer integer, Integer integer1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ClientScopeModel> getClientScopes(RealmModel realmModel, ClientModel clientModel, boolean b) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientScopeModel getClientScopeById(RealmModel realmModel, String s) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then creating a ProviderFactory to allow KeyCloak to load it:

```
public class DatastoreClientProviderFactory implements ClientProviderFactory<DatastoreClientProvider> {
    private static final String PROVIDER_ID = "google-cloud-datastore-client-provider";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DatastoreClientProviderFactory.class);
    protected Datastore datastore;

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
        try {
            datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            logger.debug("Loaded datastore instance for client provider");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Could not create datastore", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DatastoreClientProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        return new DatastoreClientProvider(keycloakSession, datastore);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }
}
```

As well as a file in META-INF/services/org.keycloak.models.ClientProviderFactory with the content

```
com.leagueapps.keycloak.DatastoreClientProviderFactory
```

But when I run the `kc.sh build` step and reload, I don't see it in the list of available providers. I have also tried "enabling" it using the documentation and setting it as my default client provider, but nothing shows up in my list of providers. Perhaps someone seeing this can figure it out.

Overall, I don't think we are "supposed" to be overriding the client provider, which is why it isn't in the Keycloak documentation, but that makes moving from a legacy application impossible. Even if we can create custom realm files, it won't work as we need a way to override some behaviors from the standard client providers.